# How to use multiple pytest conftest files in one test run with a duplicated parser.addoption?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have a pytest testing project running selenium tests that has a structure like:

```
    ProjRoot
|
|_Pytest.ini
|_____________TestFolderA
|                   |
|                   |_test_folderA_tests1.py
|                   |_test_folderA_tests2.py
|
|____________TestFolderB                
|                   |
|                   |_test_folderB_test1.py
|                   |_test_folderA_tests2.py
|                   
|
|___________TestHelperModules
|                   |
|                   |_VariousTestHelperModules
|
|____________DriversAndTools
                    |___(contains chromedriver.exe, firefox profile folder etc)
```

I have a confTest.py file which I currently run in the ProjRoot, which I use as a setup and tear down for establishing the browser session for each test that is run. It runs each test twice. Once for Chrome and once for Firefox. In my tests I just utilise the resulting driver fixture. The conftest file is as below:

```
#conftest.py

import pytest
import os
import rootdir_ref
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from webdriverwrapper.pytest import *
from webdriverwrapper import Chrome
from webdriverwrapper import DesiredCapabilities
from webdriverwrapper import Firefox
from webdriverwrapper import FirefoxProfile



#when running tests from command line we should be able to pass --url=www..... for a different website, check what order these definitions need to be in
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--url', default='https://test1.testsite.com.au')

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def url(request):
     return request.config.option.url

browsers = {
    'firefox': Firefox,
    'chrome': Chrome,
}

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', 
                params=browsers.keys())
def browser(request):

    if request.param == 'firefox':
        firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
        firefox_capabilities['handleAlerts'] = True
        theRootDir = os.path.dirname(rootdir_ref.__file__)
        ffProfilePath = os.path.join(theRootDir, 'DriversAndTools', 'FirefoxSeleniumProfile')
        geckoDriverPath = os.path.join(theRootDir, 'DriversAndTools', 'geckodriver.exe')
        profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=ffProfilePath)
        print (ffProfilePath)
        print (geckoDriverPath)
        b = browsers[request.param](firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=firefox_capabilities, executable_path=geckoDriverPath)

    elif request.param == 'chrome':
        desired_cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        desired_cap['chromeOptions'] = {}
        desired_cap['chromeOptions']['args'] = ['--disable-plugins', '--disable-extensions']
        theRootDir = os.path.dirname(rootdir_ref.__file__)
        chromeDriverPath = os.path.join(theRootDir, 'DriversAndTools', 'chromedriver.exe')
        b = browsers[request.param](chromeDriverPath)

    else:
        b = browsers[request.param]()
    request.addfinalizer(lambda *args: b.quit())

    return b


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def driver(browser, url):
    driver = browser
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

What I’d like to do is have a conftest file in each Test Folder instead of the ProjRoot. But if I take this existing conftest file and put it in each test folder and then run pytest from the project root using

```
python –m pytest
```

letting pytest pickup the test directories from pytest.ini (expecting the test folders to run with their respectively contained conftest files) I have issues with the parser.addoption --url already having been added. The end of the error message is:

```
ClientScripts\conftest.py:19: in pytest_addoption
    parser.addoption('--url', default='https://test1.coreplus.com.au/coreplus01')
..\..\..\VirtEnv\VirtEnv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py:521: in addoption
    self._anonymous.addoption(*opts, **attrs)
..\..\..\VirtEnv\VirtEnv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py:746: in addoption
    raise ValueError("option names %s already added" % conflict)
E   ValueError: option names {'--url'} already added
```

The purpose of the --url addoption is so I can override the defaults in the conftest file at commandline if I want to point them all to a different url at the same time, but otherwise let them default to running to different  url's as specified in their conftest files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue.
Error was gone after removing all cached files and venv.