# Is it possible to run pytest from some folder where conftest is found, but collect tests in another folders

Tags: pytest

I'm try to create python GUI application that will run pytest tests.
My main GUI application will have some conftest files with fixtures and hooks
The application will need to run tests in selected folder.

To test this concept, i try to run now pytest from the python with pytest.main("a/b/tests_folder") when my main python script found in different folder from the tests folder.

The issue now is how to use both conftests of my main application and of tests folder

Comment: Please update your post with any output from your test run that contains informational messages such as warnings and errors. As currently written, your post has insufficient information. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466681/how-to-use-multiple-pytest-conftest-files-in-one-test-run-with-a-duplicated-pars

Comment: Why does your application have `conftest.py`? That's normally used only in test directories.